# Binding a function with specific arguments to a onclick event in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to bind a function with specific arguments to an `.onclick()` in a context like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.textContent = board[i][j];
        button.onclick = function() {
            makeMove(i,j); //The function will always be called with the last value of i and j.
        }
        document.body.appendChild(button);
    }
}
```

I can solve this by using `makeMove.bind(null,i,j)` or `function(arg1,arg2){ return function() { makeMove(i,j); }}(i,j)` but both does not seem right because `Function.prototype.bind()` was created to bind a context to `this` and I don't want to use IIFE because it is a TicTacToe example for beginner programmers.

Is there another way to solve this problem without much complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var` to `let`. `let` introduces a different scoping mechanism then the traditional functional scope of Javascript. The `let` statement declares a block scope local variable. The `let` statment would let the **`onclick`** function handler to refer to 3 different instances of the variable `i` and similary 3 different variables for `j`.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.textContent = board[i][j];
        button.onclick = function() {
        makeMove(i,j); //The function will always be called with the last value of i and j.
    }
        document.body.appendChild(button);
    }
}
```

**Complete Working version** (Replaced board content with static text "X")

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.textContent = "x";
        button.onclick = function() {
            makeMove(i,j); //The function will always be called with the last value of i and j.
        }
        document.body.appendChild(button);
    }
}

function  makeMove(i,j){
console.log("i= " + i + "--- j=" + j);
}
```

Comment: Thats really, really cool. Didnt expected this behaviour between `let` and for loop.